# Theme override component only when descendant of other component

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to override the css of `MuiButton` but only if it's a descendant of `MuiDialog`.
[image]

In css you could do this with:

```css
.MuiDialog-root .MuiButton-root {
    border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

But I can't figure out how to do it in the theme overrides:

```js
theme.overrides = {
  MuiDialog: {
    root: {
      border: "7px solid red",
      "& .MuiButton": { border: "5px solid blue" }
    }
  }
};
```

This didn't apply the style to the button.

Is it possible to override the style of a MUI button only if it's a descendant of some specified Mui component?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-theme-override-descendent-kpdyz?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: is this what you want:  https://codesandbox.io/s/material-theme-override-descendent-forked-ts9m7?file=/src/App.js ?

Comment: @Medi no I want it so every dialog has buttons styled the same way. In the way you showed, I'd always have to add the the styles on every dialog button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classname in the theme overrides should be `& .MuiButton-root`

Answer (score 0):

I was  able to change the background of button within the dialog. Maybe you didn't use the right className:[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-theme-override-descendent-forked-ylf9g?file=/src/App.js).

```
 MuiDialog: {
    root: {
      border: "7px solid red",
      "& button": { backgroundColor: "blue" } // <- how to target MUIButton when descendent of MUIDialog?
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is helpful in this situation, but this is targeting the button tag. I was looking to target MUI Buttons and other MUI components. I was just using MUI button as an example. Is it not possible to target the MUI Button?

Comment: Your answer inspired me to try a different classname though and  `"& .MuiButton-root"` worked.